# Python: Importing Numpy after Installation Issues

Tags: python, numpy

So I installed numpy using:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install --prefix=/bla/somefolder/
```

Now everything went very smoth, but when I try to import numpy it doesnt work. So i go into this folder and I cant find numpy.py at all. I tried adding that path to PYTHONENV in my .bashrc file but that didnt work. I'm lost for ideas.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: What operating system? It would be easier to use your system's package manager, use `easy_install` or `pip`, or use a binary installer (if on Windows).

Comment: Sorry I'm on centos 6.3. I need to install from the binary. Is there a file called numpy.py or is it in some other file?

Comment: You can do `sudo yum install numpy` to install numpy for the system's Python. `numpy` has a bunch of stuff - it has python source files and also C code that is compiled into binaries (for performance reasons).

Comment: I appricate the quick responses but I do need to install numpy from source. I would just like the location of this module so I can import it. Is there any way you could look in your path?

Comment: If it installed correctly it would be under (depends on your settings) `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/` where X.X is your version

Comment: Well, if you have to build your own...go back to your numpy source code, and do `python setup.py install --user`. It should install packages into `~/.local/lib/python-VERSION/site-packages`. `--user` is much preferred to the `--prefix` method.

Comment: @lukecampbell - the `--prefix` argument would override the normal install locations.

Comment: I figured it out guys. I appreciate all the help. Have a good one :)

Comment: Well I'm going to bump everyone's answer because he got what he needed.